Add a custom notice in to WooCommerce mini cart widget
I would like it to display a message on top of a minimum order amount. Have just found code that puts a message in the cart page but would like it to show up in the side cart that opens when you click the cart widget.
Have tried the following code (and some others):
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_content', 'shop_message', 20 );
function shop_message() {
    echo '<p class="woocommerce-message">'Minsta beställning 300 kr för Sverige och 1000 kr för övriga länder.'</p>'; 
}

It Does not work, unfortunately.
The div attribute class of the widget side cart is widget_shopping_cart_content like:
<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content"> 

I would like the text to go either on top of the whole container or on the button over or under the buttons, everything is fine just if I can get it there. Preferably, a different color so it is visible.
Here is the link to the page: https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/
How can I add a message to the WooCommerce side cart?

Hi! It is the class of the widget when looking at the page. It is right now just the regular woocommorce side cart. Had some plugins that I tried but got tired of them so just thought I go with the original one and try to get a message there.

So your widget is using the classic cart/mini-cart.php template where there are some available hooks. I have answered below…
